# Add brackets to an expression with regex

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I want to add parentheses to parts of an expression.

The parts are any multiplied expressions that are NOT in parentheses.

For example, change:
a * b + c + d * e * f + g

to:
(a * b)+ c +( d * e * f) + g

another example,  change:
(a1+b1) + ( c1 * d1) + e1 * f1 *g1 * h1 + J1

to:
(a1+b1) + ( c1 * d1) + (e1 * f1 *g1 * h1) + J1

The only elements in the expression to check will be * + ( ) and variable names with no spaces, like a1 f1 p3 etc.

I came up with something but it shows the expressions WITH brackets. I want the opposite of that.

This is what I have:

```vb
Function testParen()

Dim cText As String, cPattern As String
Dim itemFound As Variant, nItems
Dim getParen As New RegExp

getParen.Global = True
getParen.IgnoreCase = True

cText = "(a1*q1) + (b1*c1) + d1*e1*f1 * (g1+h1) + (k1*m1) "
cPattern = "(^|[^*])\(([^()]+)\)"
'cPattern = "\("
getParen.Pattern = cPattern

cText = Replace(cText, " ", "")

Dim mc As MatchCollection

Set mc = getParen.Execute(cText)
nItems = mc.Count

'Debug.Print vbNewLine
If nItems > 0 Then
  Debug.Print nItems
  For Each itemFound In mc
     Debug.Print Replace(itemFound, "+", "")
  Next
Else
  Debug.Print "No items"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Changing `a * b + c + d * e * f + g` to `(a * b)+ c +( d * e * f) + g` is going to do what ? They are different. Is that the question ? Is this a regex syntax you're talking about ?

Comment: this is required as input to another function where i need all the multiplicands in a string bracketed.

Comment: Is math equations a left to right endeavor ? Or is it scope driven . And what about the precedence interpretations ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you rethink your approach and parse the expression properly rather than just inserting parentheses. Perhaps initially splitting on `+` would be simpler, rather than using a regex that you don't fully understand and can't confidently adjust.

Anyway, here is an example in JavaScript of the kind of regex that could be used. I will leave any conversion to VBA to you.

```js
const rx = /(\+\s*|^\s*)((?:\s*\w+\s*\*)+\s*\w+)(?=\s*\+|\s*$)/g;
const expression = '(a1+b1) + ( c1 * d1) + e1 * f1 * g1 * h1 + J1';
console.log(expression.replace(rx, '$1($2)'));
```

Note that the above has not been properly tested and may be brittle. I am not going to try and explain it, but you could enter the regex into for example https://regex101.com/ if you want a breakdown of how it works.

In the regex, the first `\+` could be replaced with for example `[^(\s\w]` and the second `\+` with `[^)\s\w]`, if for example you want `-` to work also.